# MYSQL LEFT JOIN with table name dependent by table column value

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

> Table1:

```
======================
|   id    |id_feature|
======================
|    1    |    4     |
|    2    |    2     |
|    3    |    9     |
======================
```

> Table_feature4

```
======================
|   id    |   size   |
======================
|    1    |   10000  |
|    2    |   12000  |
|    3    |    8000  |
======================
```

> Table_feature2

```
======================
|   id    |  radius  |
======================
|    1    |    0.9   |
|    2    |     2    |
|    3    |    3.1   |
======================
```

MY QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CONCAT("Table_feature",Table1.id_feature)) Feature ON Feature.id = Table1.id_feature
```

How can I make it work? Is there a way?
Errors I receive:

> /* SQL Error (1109): Unknown table 'Tabel1' in field list */

And if I put 4 manualy in CONCAT and without alias it say

> /* SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias */

If I'll alias "(SELECT CONCAT("Table_feature",4)) Feature" in ON condition throw this error.

> /* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'Feature.id' in 'on clause' */

I think the problem is here: "(SELECT CONCAT("Table_feature",4))" , it should return table name Table_feature4 but it only add me a column called CONCAT("Table_feature",4)

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [mcve] applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @clinomaniac to be fair, the only thing this question is missing is potential error messages, expected results, and achieved results. You can't really make an easy to reproduce MCVE of a database.

Comment: No, queries must contain direct references to tables. The only way it can "work" is to dynamically create the query; but to know how you want to construct such a query, you would have already had to query table1.

Comment: Agreed. But I am not sure what he is trying to do. The ID's from table1 do not corelate to the feature tables and I have no idea what is expected from the query.

Comment: I think the issue is that in `Table1` the "id_feature" column references the *table* the record is stored in. If my assumption is correct, this can't be done without dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the expected output is but here is my go

```
SELECT t.id,
CASE t.id_feature
  WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT size FROM feature2 f WHERE f.id = t.id) 
  WHEN  4 THEN (SELECT radius FROM feature4 f WHERE f.id = t.id) 
END AS feature_value
FROM Table1 t
```

I have a slightly different naming here but this will output the id and the value column for the corresponding id_feature table

Comment: this should work fine but the problem is that I don't have only id_feature 2 and 4 , I have at least 60. I'll try dynamic SQL as @Jacob H said, maybe this should work. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3617691 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If this works, I would suggest that you accept this answer and ask another question.  Dynamic SQL won't be much help for this.

Comment: /* SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s) */

Comment: I tested my query in MariaDb and it works there, could it really be different in MySQL? Did you change anything?

Comment: It worked ,I got error because I put * instead of size and radius,
Is there a method like:

`SELECT t.id,
CASE t.id_feature
  WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT * FROM feature2 f WHERE f.id = t.id) 
  WHEN  4 THEN (SELECT * FROM feature4 f WHERE f.id = t.id) 
END AS features_values
FROM Table1 t`

Comment: but output should have all fields from Table_feature4  when id_feature is 4 and Table_feature2 when id_feature is 2. Like in left join.

Comment: The only other column you have in the feature tables in your question is the id column and that one is already included in the query so no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery you have not a table1 (in subquery the outer table name is not in scope)

and Seems you missed the from clause in subquery 
and last you have not an id column or alias in subquery so you don't have a feature.id for ON clause

try using  somthings like eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CONCAT("Table_feature", Table1.id_feature) , table1.id
    FROM Table1
    ) Feature ON Feature.id = Table1.id_feature
```

Comment: `CONCAT("Table_feature", Table1.id_feature)` should look like `CONCAT("Table_feature", Table1.id_feature).radius` , it's table name not column

Comment: what do you mean  ?  you mean that are trying to build a table name dinamically using concat ?? .. this is not allowed  in sql

Comment: the database object  as table or column name can't be generated  dinamycally is sql  ..this possibile only with server side dinamyc sql generation tecniques .. but repeat  not in straight sql